# Inference proofs using direct proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Be sure to cite the rule and line number(s) used at each step.

b) Givens Hint: Consider the direct proof rule

1. p ^ q -> r
2. s -> q
3. ~p -> ~s

Conclusion: s->r

I'm lost on how to use direct proofs.

Answer (score 1):

From what you're given, $s \implies p$ by the contrapositive of 3, and $s \implies q$ by 2. So $s \implies p \wedge q$ and $p \wedge q \implies r$ by 1. Thus $s \implies r$.